# Parameterizing color in \addplot

Tags: pgfplots, loops, foreach

From reading Tikz and PGFPlots manuals I got an impression that using multiple loop variables syntax in `\foreach` I should be able to change color of the plots using `\clr` loop variable in `\addplot` parameters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tiny]
        \begin{axis}[
            axis x line=center,
            axis y line=center,
            restrict y to domain=-100:100,
        ]
        \foreach \d/\clr in {1/orange, 2/red, 3/green, 4/blue, 5/brown}
        {
            \addplot[smooth,\clr,domain=-5:5]{(x-\d)^3};
        }
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

That did not work. What am I missing?

Comment: `\clr` is not expanded. you need to either use `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` for single variable or define your own `cycle list`. Or

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an expansion issue (and I not the right person to attempt to explain it). But, a way to get the desired results is to use `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` which expands the contents of its body. I used `xstring` to *parse* the two components, but other techniques can be used as well.

[image]

### Notes:

- When using short macro names it is best to make sure you are not overwriting existing commands, thus the `\newcommand`s.  This technique would have shown that `\d` is an existing macro.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xstring}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\newcommand*{\diff}{}% Ensure it is not already defined
\newcommand*{\clr}{}% Ensure it is not already defined

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tiny]
        \begin{axis}[
            axis x line=center,
            axis y line=center,
            restrict y to domain=-100:100,
        ]
        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1/orange, 2/red, 3/green, 4/blue, 5/brown}
        {
            \StrBefore{#1}{/}[\diff]%
            \StrBehind{#1}{/}[\clr]%
            \edef\AddPlot{\noexpand\addplot[thick,smooth,color=\clr,domain=-5:5] {(x-\diff)^3};}%
            \AddPlot
        }
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```